# Flask FloatField throws error when trying to save data

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I created a model and forms where I defined some Float data:

```
    class Paciente(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        nombres = db.Column(db.String(40),unique=True, nullable=False)
        apellidos = db.Column(db.String(40),unique=True, nullable=False)
        fecha_nacimiento = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False)
        semanas_gestacion = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
        soplo_cardiaco = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        peso = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroSup = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        satO2_miembroSup24 = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)


class PacienteForm(FlaskForm):
    nombres = StringField('Nombres',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    apellidos = StringField('Apellidos',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=30)])
    fecha_nacimiento = DateField('Fecha de nacimiento', format='%Y-%m-%d')
    semanas_gestacion = IntegerField('Semanas de gestacion',widget=NumberInput(),validators=[InputRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=50, message="Valores de 0 a 50")])
    soplo_cardiaco = SelectField('Soplo cardíaco',
                       choices=[
                           (1, 'Si'),
                           (0, 'No')])
    peso = FloatField('peso',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
    satO2_miembroSup = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 -  miembro superior al nacimiento',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
    satO2_miembroSup24 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro superior al nacimiento 24 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
    satO2_miembroSup72 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro superior al nacimiento 72 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
    satO2_miembroInf = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro inferior al nacimiento',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
    satO2_miembroInf24 = FloatField('Saturacion de O2 - miembro inferior al nacimiento  24 horas',widget=NumberInput(),default=1.0,
        validators=[NumberRange(0, 1E+20)])
```

However when I try to save the data from forms I get an error, it says that I should introduce a valid value:

[image]

I already added the method:

```
class CommaFloatField(FloatField):
    """
    Subclass that handles floats of this format 1.2 or 1,2.
    """

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            try:
                self.data = float(valuelist[0].replace(",", "."))
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext('Not a valid float value'))
```

But I cannot save any Float value
I would really appreciate some help!
Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a browser error. If you are using Chrome, you should know that the period '.' is used as decimal mark, not the comma.

You can set the `novalidate` attr in your form to avoid browser validation.